# Questions when using Wpf & Wcf + MVVM together when creating an application (booking system)

Tags: .net, wpf, wcf, mvvm

I'm in the process of creating a booking system which a receptionist (in a hotel) can use for booking a room to a customer. I have some experience with MVC and web development, but this time I have to use Wpf which is brand new to me.

I'm thinking of using MVVM pattern, but I'm a little confused where to put model, viewmodels etc.
I'm thinking of creating 2 projects:

**Project 1:**

Is the Wpf application, the frontend part. It should run on its own computer.

**Project 2:**

Is the Wcf service application, the backend which also should run on it's own computer.

I'm confused when it comes to using MVVM together with these two projects. 
I know a viewModel is bound to a view, but the view don't know anything about the viewModel or the model.

**What I'm thinking of creating in the Wpf Application project:**

- A Models folder (not sure)
- A ViewModel folder which has the necessary ViewModels needed to create the view (like list of available rooms or something).

These viewModels are calling the Wcf service to get what is need to display the view.

**Wcf application**

- A Models folder, with all the models created (room model as an example)
- DAL folder where I create dummy data to the database tabels.
- Service folder (with services that will handle the requests from the Wpf project)

---

What also concerns me, is that what class should be the request receiver in the Wcf service application? Lets say we run these two projects on its own computer.

Wpf project "localhost:3000"

Wcf project "localhost:3001"

And in my Wpf viewModel class (or a related service to it) makes an request to the Wcf project to get room from the database. Does a WCF application have api controller to call or?

Hope someone will read this and help me out with these misunderstandings I have.

**Update:**

Got some answer from microsoft forum, they said I should leave Wcf and stick to Web Api 2.. Is it right to use Web api together with Wpf?

Comment: I haven't down-voted this myself but I'm pretty sure other people will because it doesn't fit well with the StackOverflow question format. What you're talking about is known as "full stack" development, I've had quite a bit of experience in all the technologies you've discussed and would be more than happy to offer advice if you msg me personally, but to be perfectly honest I think you'd be better off seeking help from the MSDN forums.

Comment: *"but the view don't know anything about the viewModel or the model"* Not at **all**.  The view is bound to properties of the view model and models, and templates are designed and keyed off their types.  The **view model and models** don't know anything about the view.  That allows them to be unit tested without having to deal with automating the UI.  The view model interprets inputs from the user delivered via the UI and converts them into actions, such as loading some models from the wcf service.

Comment: Thx for your post.. could I ask a simple question, in my situation should I stick to use Web Api 2 to call from my Wpf application, or should I use a Wcf service? I have experience with Web Api 2 already, but don't know if it 's right to use it here?

Comment: WCF uses SOAP which is an additional layer of abstraction on top of HTTP. As with all abstraction you don't want the additional complexity just for the sake of it, the benefits needs to outweigh the costs for your particular application. In the case of SOAP the benefits typically involve things like flexibility in transport protocol, discoverability (for public consumption) and compatibility with firewalls etc. The disadvantages include lower performance and issues surrounding session management.

Comment: In general if you control both ends of the communication, or if you need full-duplex communication, then Web Api is the way to go. If you need to expose your data publicly then go SOAP. What you really don't want to do (and trust me, I speak from experience) is fall for the trap of thinking it'll be a good idea to create a SOAP interface for external clients which you'll also consume yourself in the hope of saving development time.

Answer (score 1):

The question is why WCF ?

Does all users have access to the database ?

If the users have access to the database, then you could skip WCF and talk directly to your database.

But let's go back to your problem and Projects:

`MVVM` is just a pattern which you can use with `WPF`, in your `WCF project` there is nothing to worry about. Please read this [MSDN article about MVVM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848246.aspx)

You should keep your business logic `(Model)` in your `WCF` or `Database`, and if you are using `EF`, then all your model classes will be auto generated. And you use `EF` only in the `WCF project`.

You create your Views and ViewModels in your WPF project. Your ViewModel is kind of translater for your Model and View. Let's say you have a textbox and you want to bind it to a persons FirstName and LastName, and these properties are separated in your Model. Then you can use your ViewModel to create another Property called FullName and provide these two properties for your View.

> What also concerns me, is that what class should be the request
>   receiver in the Wcf service application? Lets say we run these two
>   projects on its own computer.
>
> Wpf project "localhost:3000"
>
> Wcf project "localhost:3001"

Your WPF doesn't have any address. It's just a normal `Windows application`.

your WCF services will look something like this `http://localhost:3001/YourService.svc`

And you can communicated whit it by adding a `ServiceReference` in your `WPF project`.

> And in my Wpf viewModel class (or a related service to it) makes an
>   request to the Wcf project to get room from the database. Does a WCF
>   application have api controller to call or?

Those `API's` you create yourself inside your `Service`.

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/97204/Implementing-a-Basic-Hello-World-WCF-Service) is how you can create a WCF service.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have some good knowledge using Web Api with Entity framework. 
Is a web api a better choice here, or should i stick to that WCF service? I don't know the normal way of doing things when it comes to Wpf :(

Comment: Just a few dissenting opinions here....the statement `model classes will be auto generated` only applies to database-first development, most places I've worked at use code-first where you write the models directly. Secondly, I wouldn't advise putting the database/ORM layer in a WCF project, I personally put it in its own project to which both WCF and WPF projects statically bind at compile time. This helps ensure clean SoC and good architecture design.

Comment: It also allows for much better integration with dependency injection frameworks (i.e. Ninject) which may need different scoping of things like database contexts and object repositories e.g. "per-request" for web services and "per-form" for WPF.

Comment: @pixel You didn't really tell why you would want to use WCF ? Is that part of the requirements ? I wouldn't recommend any WEB API with a WPF project. Just use EF directly in your WPF or do as MarkFieldman suggested with a separate project for EF